# MySQL SELECT WHERE IN array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a situation where I'd like to add a list of names in an array and use it in an SQL query.

How I do it:

```
$names = implode(',', $names);
$sql = "DELETE FROM product WHERE name NOT IN ($names)";
```

This works ok if I use id (but I can't do that here). Problem is - name can have a comma in it (i.e. - `benchpress rack, blue`) and that breaks this query. Is there a way to bypass this issue?

Comment: It probably is breaking because your names aren't quoted. Whats the error message? If `benchpress rack, blue` really is directly in your query that is invalid, strings need to be quoted.

Comment: If your using the PDO extension you can send an array as the parameter for $names. If not, implode the with single apostophys.. make your string look like this: 'benchpress rack, blue','benchpress rack,red' etc

Comment: @LaytonEverson Placeholders will need to be appended to the query though for the array to bind.

Comment: May-be solution, `= implode("','", $names);` and `...NOT IN ('$names')";`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$names = implode("','", $names);
$sql = "DELETE FROM product WHERE name NOT IN ('$names')";
```

If this is your actual code I would suggest switching to PDO, use a library, or escape your values with mysqli_real_escape_string.

Here is a link: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Here is a w3schools link for prepared statements, a decent high level view of how they work: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Here is how your statement query will run if your using PDO:

```
$query= $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM product WHERE name NOT IN (:names)");
$query->bindParam(':names', $names);
$query->execute();
```

And for mysqli it will be similar, refer to the w3schools link above for the differences.

I highly recommend you move away from the old mysql driver and at the very least switch to mysqli.

Comment: Would be nice to have a prepared statement alternative example added. :)

Comment: My solution was:

`$existing_name = "'$name'";
 array_push($names, $existing_name);` in the loop to create the array. Turned out to be enough.

Comment: @Xeen The best approach is to use prepared statements. `O'Brien` will break still this.

Comment: @chris85 ah, I see, can you post an example, please?

Comment: Good point there.

Comment: @Xeen We don't know what DB driver you are using. Layton can probably add on to this answer if you supply the information.

Comment: @chris85 mysql, as noted in the tags :)

Comment: @Xeen That's the db, not the driver. `mysql_*` (hopefully not), `mysqli`, `pdo`.

Comment: Ah, ok - this is an old project, still using `mysql_*`

Comment: @Xeen You should upgrade. Prepared statements aren't available to `mysql_`.

Comment: They are for mysqli though.